# I try to display FCM notification in background on my iPhone but it doesn't work when I send this notification with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to display Firebase Cloud Messaging's notification in background on my iPhone but it doesn't work when I send this notification with Swift.

I send a FCM to my iPhone with a HTTP request in Postman and that's work fine: my iPhone display the notification correctly in background.

When I make the same HTTP request with Swift, the Firebase's response is fine but my iPhone don't display nothing.

There is the request and the response in Postman :
[Postman's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXJY3.png)

There is the same request in a Swift Playground :

```
import Foundation

let key = "key=<my-server-key>"
let singleMessageUrl = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"

func sendSingleMessage() {
    let params: [String: Any] = [
        "to": "<my-device-token>",
        "notificiation": [
            "title": "Push from my playground",
            "body": "Push from my playground !"
        ],
    ]
    guard let bodyNotif = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: []) else {
        print("BAD NOTIF")
        return
    }
    guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: bodyNotif, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
        print("BAD JSON")
        return
    }
    print("PARAMS REQUEST:\n", params)
    print("---------------------------")
    print("JSON REQUEST:\n", json)
    print("---------------------------")
    guard let url = URL(string: singleMessageUrl) else {
        print("BAD URL")
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = bodyNotif
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue(key, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("ERROR", error.localizedDescription)
        }
        guard let response = response else { return }
        print("HEADERS RESPONSE:\n", response)
        print("---------------------------")
        guard let data = data else { return }
        guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
            print("BAD JSON RESPONSE")
            return
        }
        print("BODY RESPONSE:\n", json)
    }.resume()
}
sendSingleMessage()
```

When I launch the above request, the response appears to be OK in the console :

```
PARAMS REQUEST:
 ["to": "<my-device-token>", "notificiation": ["title": "Push from my playground", "body": "Push from my playground !"]]
---------------------------
JSON REQUEST:
 ["to": <my-device-token>, "notificiation": {
    body = "Push from my playground !";
    title = "Push from my playground";
}]
---------------------------
HEADERS RESPONSE:
 <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fcaf544c610> { URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "private, max-age=0"
    );
    "Content-Encoding" =     (
        gzip
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        138
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sun, 05 Jan 2020 09:47:15 GMT"
    );
    Expires =     (
        "Sun, 05 Jan 2020 09:47:15 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        GSE
    );
    "alt-svc" =     (
        "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\",h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000"
    );
    "x-content-type-options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "x-frame-options" =     (
        SAMEORIGIN
    );
    "x-xss-protection" =     (
        "1; mode=block"
    );
} }
---------------------------
BODY RESPONSE:
 ["multicast_id": <the-multicast_id-send-by-FCM>, "results": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x7ff55bd46aa0>(
{
    "message_id" = "<the-message_id-send-by-FCM>";
}
)
, "success": 1, "failure": 0, "canonical_ids": 0]
```

But unfortunately my iPhone receive nothing whith this Swift's request while it receive correctly the notification send whith the Postman's request.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. 
Did you try setting the `content_available: true` and `priority:  high` params? As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39581650/634958

Comment: Yes I've try that and the problem stay the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked this code on my app - it works 100%. The code itself contains a force unwrapping and is copied from the Postman, so it will require optimization in the future, but you can quickly check it if you add the device token and the server key. Also I've tested your code and found one issue - you should change `"notificiation"` to `"notification"`. Hope this help you.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sendSingleMessage()
    }

    func sendSingleMessage() {

        let parameters = "{\n    \"to\" : \"<my-device-token>\", \n\n    \"notification\": {\n    \"body\": \"From Swift code message\"\n  }\n\n  }"
        let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)

        request.addValue("key=<my-server-key>", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = postData

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                print(String(describing: error))
                return
            }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
            self.semaphore.signal()
        }

        task.resume()
        semaphore.wait()
    }

}
```